# Instragram demographic insights

Tags: facebook, instagram-api

I'm reading about Instragram api and I cannot find anything similar with facebook insights.

Basically I would like to know how many impressions/likes/shares my post had, and also I need demographic data about users who liked/share/commented on my post.

I know that some of the statistics are available through instragram api, but I could not find anything about demographic info.(gender, age, location ).

Is it possible to get some insights for demographic data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for gender, age, location.

You can get location of user if they have tagged photo, but that may not mean their actual hometown location.

You can get likes and comments information via API, but not impressions/shares

Comment: So just to make sure : there is no way to get post statistics like : percentage of men/women, age category ? I dont need information about each person who liked my post, but instead i m more interested in getting some percentage.  I have seen on the internet websites used for instagram analytics which shows some demographic information, and I was wondering how do they work.

Comment: Has this improved. Can you get demographics from instragram via the API?

Comment: I mean globally across all 1B users. Or is page scraping still used. Or paid services like napoleoncat